# P MOSFET switching with high Vgs

Tags: mosfet, switching

I designed this circuit to switch on my P channel mosfet because the Vgs will be more than -20 V (maximum Vgs) if I put the traditional design .

[image: Switching P mosfet]

Is this circuit correct or can you help me to improve it more?

thank you .

Comment: Where is the base resistor of your BJT transistor? and you need to add a zener diode in place of R2 to protect the MOSFET from excesif Vgs voltage?

Comment: Put a 5k resistor on the Base of Q2 and swap the top and bottom pin of the Q1. You can see in Q1's drawing there is a body diode, all MOSFETs have them, but in this drawing you can see that actually, if you look at the current path, now that diode will always conduct current into your load.

Comment: @codo,Asmyldof:
Thank you , you are right but my principal goal is to prevent the use of the NPN transistor(Q2).
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this circuit correct or can you help me to improve it more?

No it's incorrect - the MOSFET is upside down.

Also the BJT needs a series base resistor.

Comment: thank you , you are right but my principal goal is to prevent the use of the NPN transistor(Q2).
Is it possible ?

Comment: Are you changing the basis of your question? Your question states "Is this circuit correct" which I answered then, you said "can you help me to improve it more". Now you appear to be moving the goalposts.

Comment: I didn't know that you give only one response.

I'm sorry .

I will talk to someone who gives me responses for more than 1 question.